# How to update the value of something inside an object inside an array?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Here's the schema:

```
var pollSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    options: [{option: String, votes: Number}]
});
```

Am trying to find and increment the votes by one every time submit button is clicked.

```
Poll.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id,
        { "$inc": { "options.req.body.option.votes": this.req.body.option.votes + 1 } }
```

How to do it?

Comment: As in the marked duplicate, you need to use [**`findOneAndUpdate`**](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate) instead as `Poll.findOneAndUpdate({ "_id": req.params.id, "options.option": req.body.option.option }, { "$inc": { "options.$.votes": 1 } }, callback);`

Comment: Thank you @chridam! But I want to increment the value by 1.